# Log wso2 request to my backend server

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-api-manager

From the `API console` in `api store` i can see its `sending a curl request to the url created by wso2.`

> Like its sending a curl request to
>   https://10.222.10.185:8243/magento/1.0/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token

But how do i know in which url its hitting my backend server. I want to log that url. Here my backend url should be **http://example.com/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token** . But how do i log it on local environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can [enable wire logs](http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html) to see all request and response details.

1) Uncomment below line in /repository/conf/log4j.properties 
`log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG`

2) Restart Server.